# Removing leading Zeros upon insertion into textarea with consideration to decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, decimal, parseint

I would like to remove the leading zero when inserting into my text area:

In other words I want the leading zero to disappear when a new number is entered, and no matter how many times we I press zero after decimal point it should
give me 0 not matter how many times I press Zero
Not 0000000

also it should 
give me 1.0
Not 1.000000 not matter how many times I press Zero after the decimal point.

This is my function:

```
 function Selectnumval(id) {
        var i = parseInt("010", 10);
        var btn = document.getElementById(id)
        if (btn.click = true) {
            document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace').value += btn.value;
            document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace').style.fontSize = "40px"
            document.getElementById('TextAreaResultspace').innerText = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could coerce it into a number, and then append that number to the string.
I assume it's the `btn.value` which contains the string. Just add a `+` before the variable. So for `btn.value` you could write `+btn.value`.

Comment: Its a Calculator, thus adding the + sign after the = would remove all numbers and put the new value removing all other values.

Comment: You could use ```split``` on the string, and use coercion on each of the elements. The other alternative would be to use a regex, but I would still think it was easier to parse each element on its own.